# Why can't a close an open ADODB.Recordset?

Tags: python, adodb

My Python script uses an ADODB.Recordset object.  I use an ADODB.Command object with a collection of ADODB.Parameter objects to update a record in the set.  After that, I check the state of the recordset, and it was 1, which is adStateOpen.  But when I call MyRecordset.Close(), I get an exception complaining that the operation is invalid in the set's current state.  What state could an open recordset be in that would make it invalid to close it, and what can I do to fix it?

Code is scattered between a couple of files.  I'll work on getting an illustration together.

Comment: As I think about this, it seems to me what I'm doing makes no sense.  I create an ADODB.Recordset object.  I change the values stored in several of its Field objects. I then create an ADODB.Command object and add parameters for the changed values and for whatever key values I need to use in the where clause.  I set the values of those parameters to whatever values I have stored in the corresponding ADODB.Field objects.  I then execute the command.  Finally, I attempt to close the ADODB.Recordset object, even though it contains updated values.  I think that's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that was the problem.  Once I change the value of one of a recordset's ADODB.Field objects, I have to either update the recordset using ADODB.Recordset.Update() or call CancelUpdate().

The reason I'm going through all this rigarmarole of the ADODB.Command object is that ADODB.Recordset.Update() fails at random (or so it seems to me) times, complaining that "query-based update failed because row to update cannot be found".  I've never been able to predict when that will happen or find a reliable way to keep it from happening.  My only choice when that happens is to replace the ADODB.Recordset.Update() call with the construction of a complete update query and executing it using an ADODB.Connection or ADODB.Command object.